# Laplace transform to solve fredholm eqn

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

$$u(x)-\lambda\int_0^{a}tu(t)dt=f(x)$$

I want to solve generally for u(x) where $\lambda$ and $a$ are parameters and $f(x)$ is given. I have used Laplace transform to get the equation down to:
$$U(s)-F(s)=\lambda\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\int_0^{a}tu(t)dt$$
I havent taken diff eq in a while so my laplace is a bit rusty. If someone could help me proceed that would be great! a tip to begin with, i think wrestling with this into submission mostly on my own will provide me with some much needed momentum this semester. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your integral appears in the equation as merely a constant.  If you assume the integral exists with constant integration limits you have a constant as a result.

Comment: Should I then just assign this to some value $c_0$ then proceed? also, i forgot to mention importantly; $0<x<a$

Comment: ok, so to further this question then, if $f(x)$ is zero does that mean that the only non-trivial solution to $u(x)$ is $c_0\delta(x)$?

Comment: Your integration variable is $t$, not $x$ -- therefore, are you saying that $0\leq t \leq a$?  Is it possible that your integration limit $a$ is a function of $x$, such as $a(x)$ because that changes things.  Then, your integration limits are not constant.